# IE js sorting array by custom function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have simple custom sorting function in js:

```
function compareDesc(a, b) {
    return a.value < b.value;
}
```

I am then trying to sort an array of dictionaries:

```
var test = [];
test.push({value: 0, foo: "bar"});
test.push({value: 250, foo: "bar"});
test.push({value: 3, foo: "bar"});
test.sort(compareDesc);
alert(test[0].value);
alert(test[1].value);
alert(test[2].value);
```

It works in Chrome and Firefox where I get:

```
250
3
0
```

But in all version of IE I get:

```
0
250
3
```

So the sorting doesn't work. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is better to return 1, 0 and -1 instead of just `true` and `false`:

```
function compareDesc(a, b) {
    if (a.value < b.value){
        return 1;
    }
    else if(a.value > b.value)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/2wwBF/2

P.S. The example of the sort function from JS documentation proposes the following way:

```
function compareDesc(a, b) {
    return a.value - b.value
}
```